# define BOOST_PP_NODE_13(p) BOOST_PP_IIF(p##(13), 13, 14)

Tags: c++, boost, macros

boost 
auto_rec.hpp

What does mean p##(13) here:
define BOOST_PP_NODE_13(p) BOOST_PP_IIF(p##(13), 13, 14)

In what it translates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The '##' preprocessing operator is used to do concatenation. See [Macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html#Concatenation).
What it does is take tokens from both side of the operator and produce a single token with them.

Here's a classic usage:

```
#define foo(x, y) x ## y

foo(aa, bb) // expands to 'aabb'
```

In your case, there is no use to ## since p and (13) don't need to be concatenated to expand into a valid expression. 
It's interesting to see that ## disappeared in newest versions of [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/boost/preprocessor/detail/auto_rec.hpp).

Moreover, it seems clang doesn't like ## with parenthesis as it tries to paste 'p(' as an invalid token on its own, which result in a compiler error.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. I am aware of it. I did ask a question in wrong way. Sorry.